# Why should I check the return value of prepare?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP program to select album names from album MySQL table. I did not understand usage of `if` at preparing the statement? Why should I use `if` at all?

Line 2: Why should I use `if` statement, can't we just write it without the `if` statement?

```
$sql = "SELECT album_name FROM albums WHERE artist_id=?";
    if($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) // line 2
    {
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['artist']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($album);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
            printf("Album: %s<br />", $album);
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
 // Close the connection
    $link->close();
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: @trey Bake usage of "IF" here, at this part of the code =>    if($stmt = $link->prepare($sql)) . Cant we just state that statement without "IF" too?

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is checking for an error. When `$link->prepare()` gets an error, it returns `FALSE` instead of a MySQL statement object. If you don't check for errors, you'll get an error when you try to call `$stmt->bind_param()`, because `FALSE` isn't an object.

It's more common to write it like this:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['artist']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($album);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf("Album: %s<br />", $album);
    }
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    report_error($link->error);
}
```

The two versions are equivalent, they just combined the assignment with testing its value.

Sometimes it's written like this, mainly when initially debugging (since you usually want better error reporting and logging in a production application):

```
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql) or die($link->error);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['artist']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($album);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("Album: %s<br />", $album);
}
$stmt->close();
```

Since `die()` never returns because it terminates the script, you don't need an `if` statement to skip the rest of the code.

Comment: @Barmer Thanks alot for the help!

Comment: @BARMER And when using PDO extension, the "IF" check for errors is checked at execution part (in another code that used PDO Driver) but not at preparation part statment! Im not even able to decide where should you actually put "IF" to check for error throughout the process of declaring SQL statment to preparing it to executing it to fetching it!

Comment: It's a good idea to check in both places. They detect different types of errors.

Comment: For instance, a duplicate key error will be detected when executing an INSERT statement, not when preparing it. `prepare()` mainly just checks for syntax errors.

Comment: @Barmer Oh, that's clear now! Great help I would say. Thanks alot once again for being clear!

Comment: Do you mean it returns error when using INSERT mysql statment or do you mean when executing the line of code with which  we supply user input (binding) to prepared statment and execute it?

Comment: When you execute the INSERT statement, if the database detects a problem with the data, it will report an error during the call to `execute()`. Binding doesn't do anything with the database, it just sets up a link between the placeholders and the variables.

Comment: @Barmer Thanks for making it clear with examples at different instances (or) at different scenarios! That's a lot of patience!

Answer (score 0):

The if statement is not necessary and in fact it does not make much sense to check the result of `prepare`, but ignore `bind_param`, `execute` and `bind_result`. Your code should be consistent and check the return value of all or none of them.

Checking for return values of these functions is not needed if you have the MySQLi error reporting switched on. To enable the errors, put this line before you make your DB connection:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

If there was a problem in any of these functions then an exception will be thrown with an error message. The error will be displayed on the screen, but you should remember to switch the ini setting `display_errors` to `false` in your production environment, otherwise your errors could leak sensitive information.

Your code could look a little shorter and cleaner:

```
$sql = "SELECT album_name FROM albums WHERE artist_id=?";
$stmt = $link->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST['artist']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($album);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf("Album: %s<br />", $album);
}
```

Closing the connection is not necessary either, unless you have a good reason to do so.

Whatever you do never `echo` or `die` the contents of `$link->error` yourself. It is a very bad habit of many PHP developers, which is completely redundant. PHP can print the errors for you and it will do much better job at it than you ever would.

Comment: Ahh sorry. To be honest, the best  thing is to wrap everything in a try/catch block

Comment: @Dharman Yup, what you suggest also makes sense too! Great help bro, thanks alot for the help!

Comment: @Martin If you need to catch the errors, then you should use try/catch, but most of the time you do not want to catch the errors. Errors will bubble up and stop your PHP script. Only reason to catch them is to recover the script e.g. on a duplicate value.

Comment: Recovering the script is quite an important reason to use try/catch blocks

Comment: (especially if errors are output to screen rather than an error log)

Comment: In development the errors should be displayed on the screen. In production you will have you ini settings set to `ini_set('display_errors', 0);`, which will prevent the errors from displaying. You can still log them to a file.

Comment: It's important on StackOverflow **not** to assume everyone uses best practise. `;-)`

Comment: errors should **never** be displayed on screen; there's far too much risk of this tipping over into production. Errors should always be *logged*. Any competent PHP dev will have a tail on their error log file rather than having to read their browser

Comment: @Martin Good point I added a warning to my answer. `display_errors` is a very useful configuration setting and there is a reason it is in INI file. Every server should have its own settings properly configured for the particular environment. However, this would now be off-topic discussion for this question. If your server is misconfigured you are likely to have other problems too.